# How do I resolve dependency tree in Angular when updating from version 12 to 13?

Tags: angular, angular12, angular13

So I've been trying to get Angular to be version 13 but my local version is 12 so I try to update but it just gives me errors and I'm not sure what I should do about them. My global version is 13. I just want to know what the steps are to update from version to version in a way that minimizes errors and is at least somewhat streamlined.

The errors I get are below this line.

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: about-me@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/compiler@12.0.5
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/compiler
npm ERR!   @angular/compiler@"~12.0.5" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/compiler@"13.0.3" from @angular/compiler-cli@13.0.3
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli
npm ERR!   dev @angular/compiler-cli@"~13.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer @angular/compiler-cli@"^13.0.0 || ^13.3.0-rc.0" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@13.3.11
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm ERR!     dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"^13.3.11" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try to install with these commands if you didn't yet:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@13
ng update @angular/core@13 @angular/cli@13
ng update @angular/core@13 @angular/cli@13 --force
ng update @angular/core@13 @angular/cli@13 --legacy-peer-deps
```

Comment: I want to not use force or anything like that. That's not proper way of resolving it is it? I'd like to do things the right way. The way that would happen at the workplace.

Answer (score 0):

`npm i --legacy-peer-deps` or if it that fails again, try `ng update {{ packageName@version }} --legacy-peer-deps` for each package that you get a complaint.

As you mentioned in your comment, using `--force` is bad practice, so try avoiding that at all times. But allowing peer legacy dependencies is totally fine, especially when working with older software.

I've done that multiple times when migrating to newer versions of Angular and it worked perfectly every time.

Comment: ```ng update {{ node_modules/typescript }} --legacy-peer-deps ```  Like that? I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong or which part is what I need to update. Maybe I should update my question to add the errors I get? its a bunch of conflicting peer dependecies and could not resolve dependency type errors

Comment: No, it should be like "ng update cors@1.0.0 --legacy-peer-deps". Where "cors@1.0.0" is {{ packageName@version }}. So in your case it should be: "ng update typescript@4.9.4 --legacy-peer-deps". I gave the example with the double curly braces to represent a variables placeholder with the Mustache syntax - a known standard for data binding and templating in the web.